# Postgresql left join issue

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables

```
create table sources (
    user_id bigint,
    source varchar,
    created timestamp default now(),
    unique(user_id, source)
)
```

```
create table subscriptions (
    user_id bigint unique primary key,
    plan int not null references plans(id),
    starts timestamp default now(),
    ends timestamp default now() + interval '30' day
)
```

I try to select everything from sources when user has active subscription, I use this query

```
SELECT src.* FROM sources AS src LEFT JOIN subscriptions as sub ON sub.user_id=src.user_id WHERE now() < sub.ends
```

However, it does not return all data, the problem became clear when I tried

```
SELECT * FROM sources AS src LEFT JOIN subscriptions as sub ON sub.user_id=src.user_id
```

What may be the problem and how itspossible for me to get this info in the other way?
PS subscriptions table has rows with other user_id's.
Thank you very much!
[image: output of second sql query]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, and define what an *active subscription* is.

Comment: The first query is giving you what you want `WHERE now() < sub.ends`, which I assume constitutes an active subscription.

Comment: Which query is the image a result of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***UPDATE***

Your `left join` is working. If your image is of `SELECT * FROM sources AS src LEFT JOIN subscriptions as sub ON sub.user_id=src.user_id` then some of your users have no subscriptions.

`SELECT * FROM sources AS src LEFT JOIN subscriptions ...` only ensures every matching row in `sources` will be fetched regardless of whether it has a matching row in `subscriptions`.

---

[I wrote the rest when I thought it was a different problem, but the advice remains.]

This is possible because `sources.user_id` is not set up as a foreign key so the database cannot enforce [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity). As far as the database is concerned, `sources.user_id` is just some number. If you delete a user, their sources and subscriptions will hang around.

In general...

- Clever primary keys just bring complications. Give everything more complicated than a simple join table `id bigserial primary key` and be done with it.
- Declare everything `not null` unless you have a good reason it should be null.
- Use `on delete cascade` to clean up when a user is deleted, but see below.

```
create table sources (
    id bigserial primary key,

    -- When a user is deleted, its sources will also be deleted
    user_id bigint not null references users(id) on delete cascade,

    source varchar not null,
    created timestamp not null default now(),

    unique(user_id, source)
)

create table subscriptions (
    id bigserial primary key,

    -- When a user is deleted, its subscriptions will also be deleted
    user_id bigint not null unique references foreign key users(id) on delete cascade,

    -- Make foreign key names consistent, and use a consistent type for ids.
    plan_id bigint not null references plans(id) on delete cascade,

    starts timestamp not null default now(),
    ends timestamp not null default now() + interval '30' day
)
```

Whether to use `on delete cascade` when a deleted user still has sources and subscriptions depends on how you want to handle that situation. You might want to prevent deleting a user which still has active sources and subs, in which case leave off `on delete cascade` and handle cleaning up the user's sources and subs manually.